# NSNotificationCenter never called it's selector method

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, ios8.1

I am posting a notification to my SecondViewController . It's look like :

```
 @IBAction func NotifyButton(sender:AnyObject)
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("test", object: nil)

}
```

in my SecondViewController I am observe this notification.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "Noti", name: "test", object: nil)

}
```

And my selector method is here :

```
 func Noti(notification:NSNotification)
    {
     println( "Ohhhh Notification aaya ...are wa")
}


but control is never reach to selector method. Thanks
```

Comment: the selector name is not correct. Use "Noti:" instead of "Noti" cause your function has 1 parameter

Comment: I am try it's but it is not worked.

Comment: Can you try also `Selector("Noti:")`. I don't see another problems with your code except the declaration of Selector to use

Comment: Sir,  When i write the Selector("Noti:") then error occurs in Xcode 6.1.1 it automatically set the  selector:"Noti:" so i can't use S in Capital word in selector.....and When i am use selector:("Noti:") there was no error but no call by SecondViewController to addObservor method.

Comment: No, I mean use `selector: Selector("Noti:")` instead of `selector: "Noti:"` .

Comment: Sir, i used all the possibilities but NSNotificationCenter is not performed in my system,,,Anyone help me.

Comment: Verify if your second view controller is deallocated or not. If you call `NotifyButton` from another view controller, be sure that  your secondview controller is not deallocated.

Answer (score -1):

Sent(Post) Notification

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

Receive(Get) Notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "methodOfReceivedNotification:", name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

Remove Notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

Method of received Notification

```
 func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: NSNotification){
//Action take on Notification
}
```

Comment: Sir, Post Notification work...but Notification do not received in  second view controller ..

Comment: Sir, there was no error .....but I can't received notification......  and I am write  addObserver code inside the SecondViewController's Viewdidload( )  method.

Comment: Can you add a : to the notification name "test:" and try

Comment: Nassif Sir, i am also used a : in the notification name  "test:" and the Selector name "Noti:" also...but it is no response.....

Comment: just replace 

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "Noti", name: "test", object: nil)

with 

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "Noti:", name: "test", object: nil)
in your viewdidload methd

Comment: sir, i am set selector: "Noti:" but it not work...i am try for NSNotificationCenter past three days..but i can't understand my problem why could not addObserver method called.

Comment: @import Foundation; for objective c
import Foundation for swift
and then check

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ......but it not work..... i don't now where i am wrong...i think when the Notification is broadcast then the SecondViewController can't receive the Notification..